# Devise + Cancan: информация по их использованию на русском языке

Tags: devise, ruby, ruby-on-rails

Доброго времени суток, недавно начал учить РоР, нам дали задание сделать небольшой блог. В обязательном порядке должны быть использованы гемы Devise и Cancan. Как я понял из гугла, девайс отвечает за авторизацию и аутентификацию, а канкан связан с ролями. И вот мой вопрос:
Может ли кто-то скинуть какую-нибудь информацию по их использованию на русском языке?

Comment: принимай ответ!

Answer (score 1):

[Вот](http://programming-in-example.blogspot.com/2012/03/devise-cancan.html), например. Аж в трёх частях. Только тот, кто требует использовать cancan -- дюже странный человек: Эта байда годится только для установки самых элементарных ограничений доступа и требует больше времени на настройку, чем прописывание всех фильтров ручками.